# Beatiful soup parse page table probelm

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I want to get the data (numbers) from this page. With those numbers I want to do some math.

My current code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=45050389997905274")
c = result.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c , features='lxml')
cld=soup.select("#d03")

print(cld)

================
output : []
```

From the page-request I get this result:

```
<td id="d04" class="">2,105</td>
<td id="d03" class=""><span style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold">2,147</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:11px;color:green">305&nbsp;&nbsp;(16.56%)</span></td>
<td id="d05" class="">1,842</td>
```

From this result I only want the `<td>` ID's outputted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that page is that it's content is generated dynamically. By the time you fetch the html of the page, the actual elements aren't generated (I suppose they are filled in by the javascript on the page). There are two ways you can approach this.

1. Try using selenium which simulates a browser. You can in fact wait for the response to be generated and then fetch the html element you want.
2. The other way would be just to see any network requests being done by the page to fetch the data. If it was not loaded in the html, surely there must be another API call made to their servers to fetch the data.

On an initial look, I can see that the data you need is being fetched with this URL . (http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfodata.aspx?i=45050389997905274&c=57+). The response looks like this.

```
12:29:48,A ,2150,2147,2105,1842,2210,2105,2700,53654226,115204065144,1,20190814,122948;98/5/23 16:30:51,F,261391.50,<div class='pn'>4294.29</div>,9596315531133973,3376955600,11101143554708,345522,F,2046434489,11459858578563,282945,F,12927,3823488480,235,;8@240000@2148@2159@500@1,1@600@2145@2160@198067@2,10@1000000@2141@2161@2000@1,;61157,377398,660897;;;;0;
```

You can figure out the parsing logic in detail by going through their code I suppose. But it looks like you only need the second element `2147`.

Comment: what he's trying to get is the "id" attribute of "td" tags

Comment: Do you think selenium solves the problem?Where did you get this url from?how i can parse this data in your url that say?

Comment: @bugsb That's true. I suppose the ultimate goal is to fetch the data in the respective tag, not the id itself.

Comment: @kami Yes,selenium would solve this as it would wait for javascript to load the data. Regarding how I got the URL, you can look at the `Network` tab in developer tools to find the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might work:

```
result=requests.get("http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspxParTree=151311&i=45050389997905274")

c = result.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c , features='lxml')

for tag in soup.find_all('td')[0:2]:
    print(tag.get('id'))
```